# why float-pointing numbers don't overflow to infinity

Tags: c, floating-point

Let's say we have the following code:

```
float f = 999999999999*9999999999999999*999999999999; //a large number to make it overflow
```

so according to the float-pointing rule, the result should be infinity as:
[image]

But I checked the result's bit representation , it is not the infinity, it is some else, how come?

Comment: Always prefer `double` when using floating-point values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the values in `999999999999*9999999999999999*999999999999` are floating points, so you aren't doing floating point arithmetic. In fact, even without any extra warning options set, gcc gives me this warning for your code (clang gives a similar warning):

```
warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'long int' results in '4467987020393345025' [-Woverflow]
```

Do this instead

```
float f = 999999999999.0f*9999999999999999*999999999999;
printf("%f\n", f);
```

output:

```
inf
```

Making the first literal a floating point number forces floating point arithmetic, so you get the infinite value you want.